# In Access is it possible to have two foreign keys in a table point to a primary key in a different table?

Tags: ms-access

Heres my problem

**Employee**(EmpID, Name, JobCategoryID-->Jobs,)

**WorkRecord**(EmpID--->Employee,Hours, EmpID-->Employee)

work record logs the worker and log for who the worker worked for.

Comment: of course you can. Is there a reason you're having trouble creating this relationship?

Comment: access tell me that a field already exists and creates a new table copy in the relationships panel or is that normal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081055/vb-net-access-set-two-foreign-keys-that-refer-to-the-same-table-field/5081222#5081222

Comment: @Fionnuala sorry for late reply, but that was exactly my problem and Thanks